# Add object to sorted NSMutable array and answer index path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I have a sorted mutable array of a class called Topic.  The topics represent a an array of Publications.  I present the topics in a table, and periodically fetch new publications from a web service.  When a new publication arrives, I'd like to add to the table with an animation.

What's bothering me is the computational work I need to do to add into this array, and answer the correct index path.  Can someone suggest a more direct way than this:

```
// add a publication to the topic model.  if the publication has a new topic, answer
// the index path of the new topic
- (NSIndexPath *)addPublication:(Publication *)pub {

    // first a search to fit into an existing topic
    NSNumber *topicId = [pub valueForKey:@"topic_id"];
    for (Topic *topic in self.topics) {
        if ([topicId isEqualToNumber:[topic valueForKey:"id"]]) {
            // this publication is part of an existing topic, no new index path
            [topic addPublication:pub];
            return nil;
         }
    }

    // the publication must have a new topic, add a new topic (and therefore a new row)
    Topic *topic = [[Topic alloc] initWithPublication:publication];
    [self.topics addObject:topic];

    // sort it into position
    [self.topics sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareToTopic:)];

    // oh no, we want to return an index path, but where did it sort to?
    // yikes, another search!
    NSInteger row = [self.topics indexOfObject:topic];
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
}

// call this in a loop for all the publications I fetch from the server,
// collect the index paths for table animations
// so much computation, poor user's phone is going to melt!
```

There's no getting around the first search, I guess.  But is there some more efficient way to add a new thing to an array, maintaining a sort and remembering where it got placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly not an issue; `NSArrays` [are actually hashes](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html), and search is a lot faster than it would be for a true array. How many topics can you possibly have anyways?

Still, if you measure the performance and find it poor, you could look into using a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_tree); Kurt Revis commented below with a link to a similar structure (a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)) in Core Foundation: [CFBinaryHeap](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBinaryHeapRef/Reference/reference.html).

Another option (which would also need to be measured) might be to do the comparison as you walk the array the first time; you can mark the spot and do the insertion directly:

```
NSUInteger insertIndex = 0;
NSComparisonResult prevOrder = NSOrderedDescending;
for (Topic *topic in self.topics) {
    NSComparisonResult order = [topicId compareToTopic:topic];
    if (NSOrderedSame == order) {
        // this publication is part of an existing topic, no new index path
        [topic addPublication:pub];
        return nil;
    }
    else if( prevOrder == NSOrderedDescending && 
             order == NSOrderedAscending )
    {
        break;
    }
    insertIndex++;
    prevOrder = order;
}
```

<sub>Please note that I haven't tested this, sorry.</sub>

I'm not sure this is actually better or faster than the way you've written it, though.

Don't worry about the work the computer is doing unless it's *demonstrably* doing it too slowly.

Comment: His concern is he needs to sort the array always when he adds a new object.

Comment: @charith: My point is that the performance of the existing code is unlikely to actually be an issue. I believe this is a case of worrying how much work the computer is doing without actually seeing how much time it takes.

Comment: [CFBinaryHeap](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBinaryHeapRef/Reference/reference.html) might be a good alternative to rolling one's own B-tree.

Comment: @Kurt: Oh, boy, I hope no one thinks I was suggesting implementing a B-tree from scratch. Thanks for the link.

Comment: +1 on all these answers. thanks.  this one is especially interesting.  did not know arrays were hashes.  does that mean objectAtIndex: is not just doing a multiply to get an address?  and, yes, your bigger point is right that i'm optimizing an array that will number in the dozens.  it still bugs me.  i'm going to look at this code a bit.  can i not safely advance that insertion index as i walk the array in the for-in loop?

Comment: "Don't worry about the work the computer is doing unless it's *demonstrably* doing it too slowly." Very good advice in general. Hail Caesar!

Comment: @danh: No, I don't believe the lookup would be a multiply (except maybe for very small arrays) because the storage isn't a regular array. If you're curious, `NSArray` is implemented "on top of" `CFArray`, whose code is open: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.42/CFArray.c You can certainly do whatever you want to the index in the loop -- good point!

Comment: @IuliusCæsar (1) does the fast enumerator enumerate in order?  then i can just advance the index. (2) am i wrong, or would this miss an insertion at the first position?  maybe that else if condition is (order==Desc || (prevOrder==Desc && order==Asc))  ??  Thanks.

Comment: @danh: 1) Yes it does, and you sure can. 2) Yes, that looks right too. Sorry, I was just trying to give you the general idea -- I didn't actually test the code. Should've added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward to insert a value into a sorted list. Think about how you would insert the number "3" into the list "1, 2, 7, 9", for instance. You want to do exactly the same thing.

Loop through the array by index, using a `for` loop.

For each object, use `compareToTopic:` to compare it to the object you want to insert.

When you find the appropriate index to insert at, use `-[NSArray insertObject:atIndex:]` to insert it.

Then return an `NSIndexPath` with that index.

Edit: and, as the other answers point out, a binary search would be faster -- but definitely trickier to get right.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is correct I guess. There's another way. You can write your own binary search implementation method. (Which has only few lines of code). And you can retrieve the index where the new object should fit in. And add the new object to the required index using insertObject:atIndex: method.